# Flutter googele LineChart with String domainFn

Tags: flutter, linechart

for using google `LineChart` i can't set String for `domainFn` parameter

```
_generateData() {
  var data = [
    Task('05/10',20),
    Task('05/20',24),
    Task('05/30',25),
    Task('06/05',40),
  ];

  _seriesLineData.add(charts.Series(
    data: data,
    domainFn: (Task task, _) => task.task,
    measureFn: (Task task, _) => task.taskValue,
    colorFn: (Task task, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff990099)),
    id: 'weights',
    labelAccessorFn: (Task row, _) => '${row.taskValue}',
  ));
}
```

when i try this i get error:

```
type 'List<Series<Task, String>>' is not a subtype of type
 'List<Series<dynamic, num>>'
```

and i can't find any good reference to resolve that

my code:

```
class FragmentAddNewWeight extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => FragmentAddNewWeightState();
}

class FragmentAddNewWeightState extends State<FragmentAddNewWeight> {
  List<charts.Series<Task, String>> _seriesLineData;

_generateData() {
  var data = [
    Task('05/10',20),
    Task('05/20',24),
    Task('05/30',25),
    Task('06/05',40),
  ];

  _seriesLineData.add(charts.Series(
    data: data,
    domainFn: (Task task, _) => task.task,
    measureFn: (Task task, _) => task.taskValue,
    colorFn: (Task task, _) => charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Color(0xff990099)),
    id: 'weights',
    labelAccessorFn: (Task row, _) => '${row.taskValue}',
  ));
}

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _seriesLineData = List<charts.Series<Task, String>>();
    _generateData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Card(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  margin:EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                  child: Container(
                    height:200.0,
                    padding:EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: charts.LineChart(
                      _seriesLineData,
                      defaultRenderer: charts.LineRendererConfig(includeArea: true, stacked: true),
                      animate: true,
                      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                      behaviors: [new charts.PanAndZoomBehavior()],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Task {
  String task;
  int taskValue;

  Task(this.task, this.taskValue);
}
```

Comment: Replace `List<Series<Task, String>>` with `List<Series<dynamic, num>>`

Comment: @CopsOnRoad its not correct, because i get `error: The return type 'String' isn't a 'int', as defined by anonymous closure` error on `domainFn` parameter now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a string value for the X axis of a line chart. That value must be numeric - int or double.

Are your strings actually dates? In which case you should use a time series chart. If they are just discrete points, you should use a bar chart.

A line chart will draw the X axis points at the appropriate points along a linear axis. If the values are not evenly spaced the data points won't be evenly spaced. (The `ticks` will be, of course.)